# Nexus3 Startup Error

Tags: nexus, nexus3

[Nexus OSS 3.x](https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype). I found this error on nexus.log upon startup. Any idea what's going on? This issue just pops out suddenly; never did any changes (unless the system did something automatically?).

```
ERROR [FelixDispatchQueue] *SYSTEM org.apache.felix.configadmin - FrameworkEvent ERROR - org.apache.felix.configadmin
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle org.apache.felix.configadmin [27].
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2276) [na:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2144) [na:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371) [na:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308) [na:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file org/apache/felix/cm/impl/ConfigurationManager
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2370) [na:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2154) [na:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1542) [na:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79) [na:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018) [na:na]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1415) [na:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:4468) [na:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2221) [na:na]
```